# ViewState MAC Decryption

Tags: c#, asp.net

I seem to be running into this problem quite often. I get a bunch of errors everyday logged by ELAMH with the following in them:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.
```

As far as I know MAC is used to prevent users from injection HTML or Javascript into controls such as Labels (which don't encode HTML).

It's always on the same page, and each time with a different IP. At first I though this was a hacking attempt, but now I believe it is a coding problem. I have **machineKey** and **decryptionKey** set.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does this page have a form on it, like a "Contact Us" or something similar? There are lots of crazy robots that try to break online forms .

Comment: It has a comment form. Maybe that is it?